# Can I bring a DJI Phantom 3 Standard drone into the Dominican Republic?

Tags: legal, dominican-republic, drones

Are there any forms that I have to fill out or is it completely legal?

Comment: Why would you not be able to?

Answer (score 3):

According to http://www.phantompilots.com/the/dominican-republic-drone-laws.62421 there is a 16 page document from the [civil aviation authority](http://idac.gob.do)  website to fill in for customs, but for a drone under 2kg (like a Phantom) you don't need permission.